# Check whether a particular user has access to sharepoint programatically (C# code)

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an Excel template application where in template performs some computation based on adjustments for the data from DB.
Adjustments are provided by the user.
After the computation, the excel file gets stored on SharePoint site and a mail is sent for managers approval.
The user base keeps on changing every month. so if the user doesn't have permission to sharepoint site, the application throws out an error.
I want to add in an soft warning where In I want to display appropriate message to the user such as "You Do Not have access to the SharePoint. Kindly apply for access at : ".
I have an faceless account for sharepoint with CONTRIBUTE permission level.
I want to know how can I check if for a particular userID has required permission level using sharepoint object model.

I have tried couple of approaches available on web but was not able to iterate through permission levels for different userID.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GetUserEffectivePermissions(username)` on a `Web` instance (I assume you're using CSOM).

But I do believe you need the permission to enumerate permissions.